# how to make run Flask in Pythonista iOS?

Tags: python, ios, flask, errno, pythonista

I am using Pythonista app on iOS and I cant make Flask module work even with the most basic code.

my code is :

```py
from flask import Flask

Flaskapp = Flask(__name__)

@Flaskapp.route('/')
def helloWorld():
  return 'Woala'

Flaskapp.run(debug=True)
```

but keep receiving:

```py
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: on
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~omz-software~Pythonista3/Documents/app.py", line 9, in <module>
   Flaskapp.run(debug=True)
 File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/C4F03A05-D634-4F19-865F-6072E8D6DC38/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
   run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
 File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/C4F03A05-D634-4F19-865F-6072E8D6DC38/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1007, in run_simple
   run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
 File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/C4F03A05-D634-4F19-865F-6072E8D6DC38/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
   sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
 File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/C4F03A05-D634-4F19-865F-6072E8D6DC38/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
   exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
 File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E373BC34-F149-4EF5-9D0E-5CD807AB0771/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/subprocess.py", line 268, in call
   with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
 File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E373BC34-F149-4EF5-9D0E-5CD807AB0771/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/subprocess.py", line 708, in __init__
   restore_signals, start_new_session)
 File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E373BC34-F149-4EF5-9D0E-5CD807AB0771/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/subprocess.py", line 1261, in _execute_child
   restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

I have already installed flask trough pip in launch_stash.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I received solution on another forum by user augusto, so I believe its worth sharing it here as well, as it works perfectly.

“The only way to use debug is:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=False, debug=True)”
```

https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/5758/pythonista-flask-error-errno-1

Answer (score 2):

The iOS sandbox has [limitations](https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/1975/limitations-due-to-ios) that will prevent you from creating subprocesses

The flask development server is attempting to create a subprocess for detecting changes to your code that will then reload the server when you make changes. You can disable this by passing "--no-reload" `flask run --no-reload`. This would mean that you would have to manually restart your development server when you make changes

Answer (score 1):

Change Pythonista’s default interpreter to Python 2.7.

Comment: but why do you need python 2?

Comment: I just got that way, without having to install any packages.